# Select neighbor of element selected by class and attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have almost completed this but am stuck on an advanced selector. I am trying to select a label next to a radio button, but its a little more complex than that.

I have a select box. Only radio buttons (and their sibling labels) in which the value of the select matches the name (well part of) of the radio button.

I have a JS fiddle set up, what I am looking to do, is on selection of January, everything except Jan should be hidden, and when i select February, it should change. I'm trying to do this with just the name and no additional classes but if it comes down to it, I can add them.

http://jsfiddle.net/alpha1beta/G9Sz2/2/

Below is my working selector to get the radio button, and now am looking at how to get their `+ label` next to it

```
$('.radio([name="insights[interview_questions[' + curr_sel + ']]"])').css('display','inline');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zZt6k/

Comment: @PSL Nailed it! Very impressive! Want to make it an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/G9Sz2/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $radios = $('.radio'), $all = $radios.add($radios.nextUntil('.radio'));
$("#interview_month").change(function () {
    var $mon = $radios.filter('.radio[name="insights[interview_questions[' + this.value + ']]"]');
    var $cur = $mon.add($mon.nextUntil('.radio')).show();
    $all.not($cur).hide()
}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5b2Gg/)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the [next() function](http://api.jquery.com/next/), it returns the next [sibling](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#interview_month").change(function () {
  $('.radio , label').hide();
  var sel = '.radio[name*="' + $("#interview_month").val() + '"]';
  $(sel).add(sel+'+label').css('display', 'inline');
```

});